# How do I get this flex-direction-column layout to work in Mobile Safari?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, mobile-safari

I'm trying to achieve a particular `flex-direction: column` layout for a web page; I have it working on all desktop browsers, but it doesn't look right in Mobile Safari.

Here's a sample layout with the necessary HTML/CSS to demonstrate what I'm looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html,
            body {
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            p {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .container {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                height: 100vh;
            }

            .header {
                background: green;
                height: 150px;
            }

            .content {
                background: gray;
                flex: 1 0 auto;
                min-height: 1px; /* IE11 fix */
            }

            .contentContainer {
                background: blue;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                height: 100%;
                margin: auto;
                width: 600px;
            }

            .contentHeader {
                background: red;
                height: 75px;
            }

            .contentBody {
                background: yellow;
                flex: 1 0 auto;
                height: 0;
                overflow-y: auto;
            }

            .footer {
                background: purple;
                height: 150px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="contentContainer">
                    <div class="contentHeader">
                    </div>
                    <div class="contentBody">
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you load that up into any browser (i.e., Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11, etc.) it gives the intended effect, which is to have a vertical scrollbar for the yellow section with "Lots of content here.".

If you load the page up into Mobile Safari though, the yellow area is not visible / non-existent. I suspect it's because of the `height: 0` definition set for the `contentBody` div. The problem is, if I remove the `height: 0` definition, then the content stretches the whole page out, which I don't want either.

I want the header/footer and content header displayed at all times, and for the yellow content body area to fill in any remaining height on the page and to add a vertical scrollbar when the content body content is long enough to need one.

How can I achieve this effect with Flexbox and make it work in all desktop and mobile browsers? Thank you.

**Edit #1**: Please note that even though I set fixed heights for the header, footer, etc. in the example, on my real page, there are no set heights. Everything is dynamic, so using something like `calc(100% - 300px)` won't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to calc the content height, `100vh - 300px` (150px header and 150px footer) and calc the contentBody `100% - 75px` (75px contentHeader).

You could edit your css like this:

```
.content {
  background: gray;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  min-height: 1px; /* IE11 fix */
  height: calc(100vh - 300px);
}

.contentBody {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: calc(100% - 75px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Link to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nqmh2b0/)

**Edit:**

Try this code for full dynamic height values:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.header {
  background: green;
  height: auto;
}

.content {
  background: gray;
  min-height: 1px; /* IE11 fix */
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.contentContainer {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  width: 600px;
}

.contentHeader {
  background: red;
  height: auto;
}

.contentBody {
  background: yellow;
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.footer {
  background: purple;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
  header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="contentContainer">
      <div class="contentHeader">
      contentHeader
      </div>
      <div class="contentBody">
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
        <p>Lots of content here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, J4R. I should have mentioned this before, and I'll edit my question accordingly, but I don't have set heights for the header, footer, etc. I only did that for demonstration purposes. Everything is actually dynamic. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: you could also `calc(100vh - 10%) ` or whatever. Depends what your dynamic values are.

Comment: When I say "dynamic", I mean that the heights of those elements are not dictated by any height declarations, px or %, in the CSS. They're 100% (no pun intended) determined by the content within those divs, and the content does dynamically change sometimes.

Comment: I edit my answer. If you set the height values `auto` and some more adjustments, it should work like this

Comment: J4R, thanks for all your comments and feedback. I tried your solution, and while it worked on desktop browsers, it didn't work on Mobile Safari.

Comment: could you describe, whats happening in your safari mobile view? Or whats the problem?
It's working in my emulated mobile view..

Comment: J4R, I'm not using an emulator. I'm looking at it on an actual iPhone 6s in Mobile Safari, but basically, the long content section scrolls off the screen and the footer is non-existent. For what it's worth, it does display fine on desktop browsers. Looks fine to me in an emulator as well, so that's not a good judge in this case, unfortunately.